# Twilio API in Python Returning AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'studio'

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio

I am trying to list executions from my Twilio flow by using this code: 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution?code-sample=code-read-executions-filtered-by-date

I have also tried the v2 code:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/execution#read-a-list-of-executions

But every time I run the Python file I get the returned statement: 
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'studio'

Unsure what I'm doing wrong...I am able to use other commands such as:

```
completed_calls = client.calls.list(status='completed', to=MyNumber, limit = 10)
```

Which works fine.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check to see if you have more recent version of the Twilio Python helper library?

`pip show twilio`

`pip install --upgrade twilio`

twilio-python (Changes)

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Comment: Thanks! I feel so silly but yea that worked -- I just assumed it wasn't needing an update since I was referencing what felt like older documentation. But yea -- that worked for me. Thanks! :)